# VBA: Wait until browser loads more than once

Tags: vba

I've been working on a program to fill up a form after the webpage is loaded, its working well with this:

```
 Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

After this my code loads, fills up the form and the click the log in button.

Here comes the problem, i've been trying to click a button right after the new page loads, so i tried the same loop method to accomplish this, but it is not working.

I said to myself, this can't be, it has to work!, so i tried making a code for a search on  youtube and for my surprise it did work, it searched a video and then i could select the one i wanted.

So if it does work, why it doesnt with my login page?

I noticed the page does not reach the next page right away after logging in, it loads a page and then quickly it loads another one and reroutes to that one.

Do you have any idea how to wait until the browser reaches that point?

whole code until now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer


 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

Dim MyURL As String
 On Error GoTo Err_Clear
 MyURL = "url"
 Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
 MyBrowser.Silent = True
 MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
 MyBrowser.Visible = True
 Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
 HTMLDoc.all.user.Value = "user"
 HTMLDoc.all.pass.Value = "pass"
 For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
 If MyHTML_Element.getAttribute("src") = "url" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
 Next

Set MyBrowser.document = HTMLDoc

Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

 Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
 For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
 If MyHTML_Element.getAttribute("name") = "name" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
 Next


Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: the code works for clicking buttons on youtube, but not in the logging thing im working on and i just foud out that the html code is full of frameset tags, can that affect how the program reads the elements in it? or the html?